# Restrict access to google cloud storage via TLS client authentication

Tags: google-cloud-storage, tls1.2

I have a bucket in google cloud storage. I would like to limit read-access to the files in the bucket by means of TLS client authentication. The intention is to download the file with wget, specifying a client certificate and having access only if the client access is allowed in the cloud.

Comment: You want the client authenticated by certificate and not by OAuth token, correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible.